# Angular google Map will not render and throws no errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, maps

I am new to angular but I think I have everything right. It is a pretty simple setup.

Here is the app

```
var appLocations = angular.module('locations', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']).config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {

    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        // key: 'I am not providing a key',
        v: '3.17',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
});

appLocations.controller('LocationsController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/json/locations/')
        .then(function(res){
            $scope.locations = res.data;
        });
});

appLocations.controller('MapController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/json/locations/')
        .then(function(res){
            $scope.locations = res.data;
        });
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
});
```

Here is the markup

```
<div class="main1-in" ng-app="locations">
        <div ng-controller="MapController">
            <ui-gmap-google-map></ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
        <div class="health-care large-12 medium-11 small-12">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('Welcome')?>
        </div>
        <div class="location large-12 medium-12 small-12" ng-controller="LocationsController">
            <h2>LOCATIONS</h2>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" class="text-field" value="Find a location" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search...">
                <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="location-carousel large-12 medium-12 small-12">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="location in locations | filter:search">
                        <div class="location-in"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalClinic">
                            <img src="{{location.thumbnail[0]}}" alt="img" width="273" height="157">
                            <h6><span itemprop="name">{{location.Name}}</span></h6>
                            <p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                                <span itemprop="streetAddress">{{location.address1}} {{location.address2}}</span><br>
                                <span itemprop="addressLocality">{{location.city}}</span>,
                                <span itemprop="addressRegion">{{location.state}}</span>
                                <span itemprop="postalCode">{{location.zip}}</span>
                            </p>
                            <small itemprop="telephone">{{location.phoneNumber}}</small>
                            <a href="{{location.permalink}}" itemprop="url">Visit location page</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I get no errors in the console. The rest of the application renders but the map itself does not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you make a working example in plnkr.co?

Comment: why aren't you providing a key ?

Comment: My understanding is that they API key is not required. @cs1193 I will see what I can put together.

Comment: So I tried to put an example together on plnkr.co but could not get any of it to work. I am working at getting a working version up online so you guys can look at it. Till then any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @AaronBlakeley could give me the some example content of /json/locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your operations are correct according to documentation, except for one thing, you need to mention a map center and the zoom level for the map to start with, see Quickstart documentation

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

`map.center` and `map.zoom` gets picked up from the MapController you have provided, a local-copy works for me. Check if you hold any problems with other parts of code.

and definitely,

```
.angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }
```

into your CSS, or dynamically set height accessing the DOM.